# Преобразование данных

Tags: android, kotlin, архитектура, cleancode

Из Domain слоя получаю `List<Point>` в `ViewModel`.

```
class Point(val lat: Double, lon: Double, titile: String)
```

Во ViewModel необходимо из `List<Point>` получить `PolylineOptions`, для этого сделал маппер

```
interface PointsToPolylineMapper : Mapper<List<Point>, PolylineOptions>
```

и есть реализация

```
class DefaultPointsToPolylineMapper @Inject constructor(val context: Context):
    PointsToPolylineMapper {
    override fun transform(value: List<Point>): PolylineOptions {
        val polylineOptions = PolylineOptions()
        val color = Color.parseColor("#24AEB6")
        value.point?.map {
            polylineOptions.add(LatLng(it.lat, it.lon))
        }
        polylineOptions.color(color)
        return polylineOptions
    }
}
```

`polylineOptions.color(color)` - вообще должен быть в маппере или все таки где-то в другом месте? Обязанности маппера ограничить только маппингом или считается нормальным доп настройки внутри маппера?

Сейчас, например, необходимо дать возможность пользователю настраивать цвет и размер линий вручную. Ок, сделал сохранение настроек пользователя, но непонятно в каком месте их использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У каждого класса должна быть одна обязанность.

У `DefaultPointsToPolylineMapper` уже есть четкая обязанность. Имеет смысл добавить `UserSettingsAwarePointsToPolylineMapper`, который будет декоратором для `PointsToPolylineMapper` и уже его использовать в `ViewModel` предварительно завернув в него `DefaultPointsToPolylineMapper`.

`UserSettingsAwarePointsToPolylineMapper` должен сначала вызвать того, кого он оборачивает, а потом применить свою логику, т.е. достать значения сохраненных настроек пользователя и применить к `polylineOptions`. Для этого придется в `UserSettingsAwarePointsToPolylineMapper` внедрить как зависимость сервис `UserSettingsService`, который будет позволять доставать настройки.

Есть альтернативный вариант. Создать `ParametrizedPointsToPolylineMapper`, у которого толщина и цвет задаются в момент создания экземпляра маппера. Далее мы не используем фиксированный маппер в `ViewModel`, а создаем его динамически с помощью `UserSettingsAwarePointsToPolylineMapperProvider`.

Comment: Вроде вариант хороший, но все никак не могу свыкнутся с мыслью, что  UserSettingsAwarePointsToPolylineMapper именуются как Mapper. По сути он же не занимается маппионгом, а задает какие то настройки.. Или норм?

Comment: Тут как посмотреть. В конечном итоге с точки зрения его клиентов, от преобразовывает один тип в другой, так что он и есть маппер. То что он сам делает только малую часть и делегирует основную работу еще кому-то, это нормально. Ведь маппер может потребовать какую нибудь сложную логику, например, преобразовать звук в спектр, и основную работу будет делать целая куча других классов, которые он вызовет и скоординирует их работу. Конечно, есть альтернативный вариант, добавил в ответ.